# Is there a Bootstrap vertical dropdown responsive menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Like this one http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/ but vertical and Bootstrap-style? I am not so good in css to remake it to Bootstrap style (too much css code).

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Bootstrap's menu already collapses to a vertical mobile menu, and you could use nested elements or the collapse method to do the accordion.

Comment: Here's a basic example: http://www.bootply.com/render/QutOBjvgha

Comment: @isherwood I think he means by `Vertical Menu` not `Default Horizontal Menu`.

Comment: The menu on the linked page certainly isn't vertical (except for mobile, like Bootstrap). Clarification is badly needed, and the question is probably off-topic anyway.

Comment: Just select the `Vertical Main Menu` from the provided Link and you'll get the idea what he's looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `data-hover="dropdown"` where you'd put `data-toggle="collapse"`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Sorry I did not understand when you said vertical but now I think I do.  So the below will give you a horizontal collapse but you can use that as part of your vertical menu.

You would need to create two tables. One table holds all your buttons/links and the other collapses and un-collapses the panel.  For example if you have 10 buttons on the left hand table (10 rows , 1 col). You would have 10 collapsible panels in the right hand-side table which would give the impression of a vertical menu. At least that's how I would attempt it :)

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

```
<button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
Some text..
</div>
```